# AntD Change color of Icon

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using v4 of AntD and have imported @ant-design/icons in order to use LeftOutlined.

In the docs for antd icons (https://ant.design/components/icon/) It lists the following for the fill attribute:

> **fill**   |   Define the color used to paint the svg element   |   *string*   |   'currentColor'

I assumed that this meant I could do this but it is not working:

```
<RightOutlined fill="#4E89FF" />
```

Instead for now I am using the style attribute and is working:

> **style**   |   The computed style of the svg element   |   *CSSProperties*   |   -

```
<LeftOutlined style={{color: "#4E89FF"}} />
```

---

.
.

Did I misunderstand the **fill** attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That section of the docs you reference is for custom SVGs that you import. The api for their icons such as the one's you're trying to use are [above that](https://ant.design/components/icon/#Common-Icon).

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I messed that! It looks like I am using the correct method.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to change the color of the icon provided in the document is to use the twoone color icon component.

Example

```js
import { EditTwoTone } from "@ant-design/icons";
...

return (
...
  <EditTwoTone
    style={{ fontSize: "20px" }}
    twoToneColor={isTrue ? "black": "red"}
  />
...

)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just another (better, somehow) way when using defaul palette. Colors are `array` where each item is the hex value. Refer to [colors](https://ant.design/docs/spec/colors):

```jsx
import { red } from "@ant-design/colors";

return (
    <MinusCircleOutlined style={{ color: red[5] }} />
);
```